# How to use Regular Expressions to count an exact number of white spaces within a sting

Tags: regex

Very very simple question I think.....I am attempting to get an match for the following:

```
17 SEP 2014                         2
```

Currently the following expressions get a match by ignoring the white spaces between the date and the number (note: the number can be more than a single digit):

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\ (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\s\d{4}\s* ([0-9]+)$
```

Probably not the most elegant, but as a total beginner, it's a start and does get me a match.

What I really need to be able to check though, is that there is exactly 25 white spaces between the date and the digit though. Can anyone tell me how I can get a match only if there are exactly 25 white spaces?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match exactly 25 whitespace characters, you can use:

```
\s{25}
```

What you used (`\s*`) will match any number of characters, including zero.

Comment: Brilliant.....I knew it was going to be something real simple! Works a treat just like that.